# infinite summation of derivatives of a convergent function

Tags: derivatives, convergence-divergence, summation, taylor-expansion

How can I simplify this summation 
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left[1-\sum_{n=0}^{i-1}(-1)^n \frac{a^n}{n!} \left. \frac{d^n}{dt^n} f(t)\right|_{t=a} \right] $$

if $f(t)$ is equal to $\left(\dfrac{b}{t+b}\right)^2$

I thought about using taylor series
where 
$f(x)=f(c)+f'(c)(x-c)+f''(b)(x-c)^2/2!+\cdots.$
Now taking $x=c-a$
then $f(c-a)=f(c)-a.f'(c)+f''(c)a^2/2!-\cdots+.$

An update:
from the cauchy integeal 
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (z-z_0)^n \frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}$$
then taking $z_0=a$ and $z=0$
$$f(0)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (-1)^n a^n \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}$$

Comment: any own thoughts?

Comment: It seems like it is in the form of tylor expansion. $f(a)-af'(a)+.....+ \frac {a^n}{n!}/f''(a)$.... Some technical papers uses a similar equation and the results in a finite number depending on $a$.

Answer (score 0):

With help of a nice professor, this summation is approximated to two geometric series. 
$$f'(a)=  \dfrac{-2b^2}{(a+b)^2}$$
$$f''(a)=  \dfrac{6b^2}{(a+b)^3}$$
$$f^{(n)}(a)=  \dfrac{(-1)^n(n+1)!b^2}{(a+b)^{n+2}}$$
sub. in the original equation
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty [1-\sum_{n=0}^{i-1} \frac{a^nb^2(n+1)}{(a+b)^{n+2}}]$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty [1-\left (\dfrac{b}{a+b}\right)^2\sum_{n=0}^{i-1} (n+1)\left (\dfrac{a}{a+b}\right)^n]$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty [1-\left (\dfrac{b}{a+b}\right)^2[\sum_{n=0}^{i-1} \left (\dfrac{a}{a+b}\right)^n+\sum_{n=0}^{i-1} n\left (\dfrac{a}{a+b}\right)^n]]$$
The first term is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Generalized_formula) and the second term is first derivative of a geometric series.

The final result will be $$\left(\dfrac{b+2a}{b}\right)$$

Comment: Using Cauchy integral posted above will give the same result but it is a longer approach.